# SSRS Parameter issue (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Having an issue where I have created a report with a shared data source and several shared data sets. The report has 2 parameters one dependent on the other. This was working fine until just recently. Now any report I create with a parameter does not work. I've tried creating a simple empty report that has an embedded DataSet:

SELECT ClientId, Name From Client

Then have the parameter use this query to populate available values (Value = ClientId and Label = Name).

When I preview in BIDS (VS-2008) it works just fine.

When I deploy and run the report I get the following error:

An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)
 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. The statement has been terminated.

There are no expressions and I've deleted all old datasets that used to have an expression. Seems like SSRS has something cached though I have deleted Internet Cache and deleted the datasets from SSRS and went into the DB and deleted everything I could. Anyone else out there experience this issue?

Thanks

Comment: check two things, 1) Data type of your parameter 2) what are you passing to the query, value or Label of parameter. The error messages suggests you are passing a string to an int column in your query.

Comment: I would look into the connection failure. Perhaps your most recent deployment data source credentials did not come across. This can happen when you copy a report and pastes into another project. Check the Data source Credentials.

Comment: @M.Ali the data types are correct it is a very simple query as you see. Also as I've mentioned before it works when in BIDs in preview mode just not in deployment

Comment: @lrb the connection is fine as the parameter list is getting populated. The rest of the report is empty so no other queries are being executed.